# Creating a S3 policy to allow full access to one S3 subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a AWS S3 policy to allow full access to a specific S3 subfolder but nothing else. In the example below there is a dev named Bob. I created a directory dedicated entirely to Bob and want to give him full read/write access to this S3 folder only (the bob folder) by logging in to the console.

This is what I tried, although when attempting to access the bob directory I am getting an access denied error. I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::/mydir/devs/bob/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember S3 objects are the full key name, so you have given permissions to:

```
/mydir/devs/bob/*
```

Which represents all keys prefixed with `/mydir/devs/bob/`, but wouldn't include the key `/mydir/devs/bob` itself, which is your "folder". It's also missing a bucket name (`bucket-name/mydir/devs/bob/*`) This means the user can't use a list action on the "folder" or it's parent folders. So, Bob can't navigate to his folder.

There is a great walkthrough on creating user specific subfolders available on the AWS Blog, [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/). We can break that info down to fit your use case, the statement ids would look like this:

### Allow Bob the needed permissions to see the bucket list in the console:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
  "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
}
```

### Allow Bob to navigate to his folder by allowing listing on each parent directory

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
  "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","mydir/","mydir/devs/","mydir/devs/bob"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
}
```

### Let Bob list any files and folders inside his folder

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
  "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
  "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["mydir/devs/bob/*"]}}
}
```

### Finally, let Bob take any actions on anything inside his folder

```
{
   "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
   "Action":["s3:*"],
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/mydir/devs/bob/*"]
}
```

### This combines to look like this:

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","mydir/","mydir/devs/","mydir/devs/bob"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["mydir/devs/bob/*"]}}
   },
   {
      "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
      "Action":["s3:*"],
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/mydir/devs/bob/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

The provided documentation also gives a great example on doing this by using the `${aws:username}` variable inside the policy so this can be applied to groups.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for exactly the same need. Some of the combinations seem counterintuitive (why do I need both `ListAllBuckets` and `ListBucket` - but it seems to not work without it):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mydir"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mydir/devs/bob/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Also, I think `ListBucket` requires a bucket (that is, `mydir` in your example). I don't think it works with the key (or folder), like `mydir/devs/bob`

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help, however, this did not work. When attempting to upload a file into the bob directory, it uploads unsuccessfully.

Comment: actually, I see the difference with my scenario... take a look at Conditions: `mydir/devs/bob` is **not** a resource. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html